# Como formatar e calcular 1.000.000,00 no PHP?

Tags: php

Olá,

Tenho valores como 1.000.000,00 que preciso somar e depois exibir.
Estou fazendo isso:

```
<?php
$vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao = str_replace(',', '.', $vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao);
$vlDepreciacao = str_replace(',', '.', $vlDepreciacao);
$vlgastoPessoalDeProducao = str_replace(',', '.', $vlgastoPessoalDeProducao);
$vlOutrosCustosIndiretos = str_replace(',', '.', $vlOutrosCustosIndiretos);

$custoIndireto = $vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao + $vlDepreciacao +   $vlgastoPessoalDeProducao + $vlOutrosCustosIndiretos;

echo number_format($custoIndireto,2,',','.');
?>
```

mas sempre aparece esse erro:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

e aponta para a linha do echo.

Fora que o valor de 185.700,00 está aparecendo como 185,70

Comment: `$vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao` qual é o valor inicial?

Comment: O valor é de 185.700,00

Comment: VoC6e quer dizer, qual o valor de $custoIndireto? É pra ser 804.230,00

Comment: antes de executar essa linha `$vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao = str_replace(',', '.', $vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao);´ qual é valor de `$vlgastoGeralDeFabricacao`?

Comment: O valor é esse que informei acima @VirgilioNovic, 185.700,00

Comment: Esses valores são pegos de um formulário.

Comment: Então pode vir assim: `1.000,00`?

Comment: Não, pois dessa forma 1.000,00 o valor não é somado, o php não calcula valores monetários com "," vírgula.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45371/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-gustavosevero).

Comment: Tente desta maneira; some todos os numeros (sem usar `str_replace`) e depois exiba com o `number_format` e veja o que aparece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tome bastante cuidado com valores no formato brasileiro, precisa retirar o `"."` e no lugar da `","` coloque o `"."`;

Com [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) onde:

- primeiro parâmetro passe um array de pesquisa;
- segundo parâmetro passe um array de alteração;
- terceiro parâmetro o valor a ser alterado.

---

```
<?php    

  $v1 = "1.000,00";
  $v2 = "2.000,00";

  $vf1 = str_replace(['.',','],['','.'], $v1);
  $vf2 = str_replace(['.',','],['','.'], $v2);

  $vf  = $vf1 + $vf2;

  echo $vf; // saída sem formato 3000

  echo number_format($vf, 2, ',', '.'); //saída: 3.000,00
```

e por fim formate novamente com [number_format](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php) ( `number_format($vf, 2, ',', '.')` ).

Comment: Vou tentar isso.